# Sum specific number of rows in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, sum

I have a matrix (p) with a dimension of [4099,4217], I want to sum in axis= 0 means that I want to sum the rows, but not all the row, rows between (16, 3276). And I want to do this for all columns.
Here is a code I wrote, but I know the output is not correct.

```
for i in range (16, 3276):

    out= np.sum (p [:,i])
```

Comment: You want to sum row to return just one scalar or a single row containing sum of all column ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got the answer in other comment

Answer (score 0):

```
sum_p = p[16:3276,:].sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
```

Sum for each row:

Including 3276th row:

```
x = np.ones((4099, 4217))
x[16:3277,:].sum(axis=1)
```

Not including 3276th row:

```
x = np.ones((4099, 4217))
x[16:3276,:].sum(axis=1)
```

If you would like to sum all of sums for those rows:

```
np.sum(x[16:3276,:].sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a complete answer. Just I think it should be axis=0

Comment: Check yourself: x = np.ones((10,3)), np.sum(x, axis=0).shape, np.sum(x, axis=1).shape